# How to set get params with history.replaceState({}, 'foo', "/index.html?id=redirect" ) in Opera

Tags: javascript, opera

So it looks like in Opera this `history.replaceState( {} , 'foo', "/index.html?id=redirect")` would not set ?id=redirect in browser URL(in chrome and FF it is fine).

But it works fine with `history.replaceState( {} , 'foo', "/index.html/id/redirect")`

Is there any way to display it in browser URL like /index.html?id=redirect (with get params)? Thanks.